# ng2-file-upload - how to add MIME type for '.dmg' file format?

Tags: file, file-upload, ng2-file-upload

I am trying to allow `.dmg` file for upload. but not working. what is the correct way to add mime for that?

here is my try:

```
'.mp3- 'audio/mp3'
'.aif',- 'audio/aiff'
'.wav’ - 'audio/wav'
'.zip'- 'application/x-zip-compressed'
'.pdf' - 'application/pdf'
'.dmg' - application/x-apple-diskimage -> not working!! ( using windows 10 )
'.exe' - 'application/x-msdownload'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you should use **'application/octet-stream'**